# Can a Docker container access env variables I've set on the server?

Tags: docker

I have a twitter bot which I am attempting to deploy to my server with Docker; I don't want to save my API keys & Access Tokens in the code, so I access them via env variables.

I ssh'ed into the server and exported the keys & tokens in my ~/.profile, yet when I run the Docker container on my server, I get an error as if my keys/tokens are incorrect.

I'm new to Docker so I have to ask - Is my running Docker container able to access these env variables? Or do I have to set them another way such that my Docker container can see them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker can't access the env vars on the server. You need to pass them explicitly when running the docker using `-e` / `--env` flag.

Example: `docker run --env VAR1=value1 --env VAR2=value2 ...`

Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, kind of unfortunate that I'll have to pass in those env variables each time I run it. I may just whip up a bash script to automatically run it and pass them in from the server's env variables.

Comment: You may be interested in `--env-file` option to avoid creating bash script ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)). Also sometimes `docker-compose` can greatly simplify your life by keeping everything together (you don't pass numerous flags to `docker run` with compose, just `docker-compose up` with all configuration taken from `docker-compose.yaml` single file; it is even more useful if you have more than one container)